# How to get data from span tag angular js 1

Tags: angularjs, angular1.6

I have table

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>N0</th>
            <th>Produrce</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="paym in prices">
            <td>{{paym.num}}</td>
            <td>{{paym.name}}</td>
            <td>{{paym.payment}}</td>
            <td>{{paym.unit}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><span class="sp-total-lbl"> Total Amount</span></td>
            <td align="right"><span id="span-amount">{{getTotal())}}</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <button ng-click="check_verify()" class="btn-primary">
                    <i class="material-icons">add</i>Check
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Here** is `getTotal()` function

```
$scope.getTotal =function(){
 var total = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < $scope.prices.length; i++){
    var p = $scope.prices[i];
    total += parseInt(p.payment);
 }
 return total;
}
```

**What my question?** I want ask when I click button `Check` call function `check_verify()` , I want alert total price.

```
$scope.check_verify =function(){
    alert($scope.getTotal);
}
```

I trying like this but it not get result data, it return function code, Any one seguest me how to get valus data from total price?

Comment: alert($scope.getTotal());  you are missing ()

Comment: Remember to accept an answer so this gets marked as resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `()` to make the function call.

```
$scope.check_verify =function(){
    alert($scope.getTotal());
}
```